# SHLoadNonloadedIconOverlayIdentifiers doesn't work in the WinXP?

Tags: windows-shell, shell-extensions

In the current project, I'm making an icon overlay. The actual implementation is completed.

And I made sure that it worked well in WindowsXP and Windows7.

But I want to appear to overlay icon immediately without restarting the explorer process.

So I found a way that [SHLoadNonloadedIconOverlayIdentifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762215%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function signals the shell and then load the nonloaded Shell Extension dll.

I make sure in the MSDN that minimum supported clinet of this function is Windows 2000 Professional.

In Windows7, this function worked fine, but it did not work in WindowsXP.

I would like to know why.